# What are the possible degrees for $\Bbb C[x]$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

If $f(x) \in \Bbb C[x]$ is a non constant irreducible polynomial, then what are the possible degrees of $f(x)$? What if $f(x)$ is in $\Bbb R[x]$?

Comment: One. That's D'Alembert-Gauß' theorem.

Comment: In $\mathbb C[x]$: it's degree 1, and in $\mathbb R[x]$: it's degree 1 and 2.